# Gerrit - Replicating to github

Tags: github, gerrit

I configured gerrit replication via

```
[remote "github"]
  url = git@github.com:MYUSERNAME/${name}.git
  push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  timeout = 5
  replicationDelay = 0
  authGroup = Administrators
```

I can log in to github with the gerrit2 user as far as it is allowed from github site. Github is in the known hosts.
However I get the following error:

```
[2013-06-04 20:04:54,472] ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : Cannot replicate to git@github.com:MYUSERNAME/All-Projects.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:MYUSERNAME/All-Projects.git: reject HostKey: github.com
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.listRemote(PushOne.java:409)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.doPushAll(PushOne.java:357)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.generateUpdates(PushOne.java:350)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:298)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:252)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:207)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:71)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:186)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:183)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:337)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: github.com
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:712)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

Similar problem for ssh access
with

```
url = ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/MYUSERNAME/${name}.git

[2013-06-04 21:22:06,072] ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : Cannot replicate to ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/MYUSERNAME/All-Projects.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/MYUSERNAME/All-Projects.git: reject HostKey: ssh.github.com
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.listRemote(PushOne.java:409)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.doPushAll(PushOne.java:357)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.generateUpdates(PushOne.java:350)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:298)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:252)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:207)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:71)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:186)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:183)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:337)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: ssh.github.com
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:712)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: If your problem is not about the All-Projects.git, please check if it's really the exact same message for the other projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log in (via SSH) as the user under which Gerrit is running.

I recommend you to set up a `~/.ssh/config` for the Gerrit user like this:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /path/to/the/private/key
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

This sets up your SSH key ignores warnings about the (initially) unknown host.

If you can then connect via `ssh github.com`, we're almost there. Then try to clone the Github repository using the SSH URL.

Afterwards let Gerrit try to replicate again.

Plus then I would recommend to remove the `authGroup` setting from the `replication.config`.

Comment: thanks very much! I have GitLab docker installed with mapping 2289 to 22. With this config, my Gerrit's replication plugin can replicate changes to GitLab.

Comment: This solution isnt working for my case, However, in my case instead of github its gitolite. I have setup this ~/.ssh/config and still fails with the same stacktrace.

Comment: That's a pity to hear. You're free to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: please see the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462161/gerrit-replicating-to-gitolite-fails

Answer (score 1):

Create a group "Github Export" and give this group read access only to the repos you want to export (or explicitly deny read access for All-Projects, which is kind of a meta project carrying only settings inherited by other projects). When you then set the `authGroup = Github Export`, only repos to which this group has access are exported.

Please keep in mind that since Gerrit 2.5 the group has to be visible to all members (it's a setting of the group), caused by extracting that functionality into a plugin. See the Gerrit list archive for that.

One other idea might be to use [this not yet merged patch](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/37711), which allows you to set patterns for what repos you want to replicate to a certain remote.

The last option would be to simply ignore this error message. Replication of other repos can still work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I think to problem is not related to the security groups. The problem appears with real projects as well.

Comment: The authGroup would only help you to prevent replication errors of repos that are not on gitub.