# "gerrit: replicate: not found" even after installing replication plugin

Tags: git, github, rsa, gerrit

I am using gerrit for code review and I use, replication plugin to keep the repo in sync with github.com .

But, the replication is not working. It throws me error:

```
[2014-01-16 11:23:04,694] ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : Cannot replicate to git@github.com:visitvinoth/gerrit_prj_1.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:visitvinoth/gerrit_prj_1.git: reject HostKey: github.com
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.listRemote(PushOne.java:468)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.doPushAll(PushOne.java:416)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.generateUpdates(PushOne.java:409)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:357)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:340)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:267)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:78)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:240)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:237)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:360)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: github.com
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:780)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

I have already registered the RSA key of the gerrit user in github.com on my account.

When I try triggering the replicate command manually,

```
ssh -p 29412 vinoth@xxx.xxx.xx.xx gerrit replicate gerrit_prj_1
```

I get the error,

```
gerrit: replicate: not found
```

Please help

Comment: You try to trigger the replication with the wrong command. See the [documentation](https://review.typo3.org/plugins/replication/Documentation/cmd-start.html). The correct syntax is: `ssh -p 29418 review.example.com replication start`.

Comment: @StephenKing, Thanks. Your command works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the gerrit server, you can use [StephenKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400222/stephenking)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16977340/6309), and add a `~/.ssh/config` file which will specify where are the key to use:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /path/to/the/private/key
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

But if you used default `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (which should have been picked up by ssh), then check on that same Gerrit server the value of `$HOME`, as I mention in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992354/6309).

As [StephenKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400222/stephenking) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154527/gerrit-replicate-not-found-even-after-installing-replication-plugin/21155548#comment31843293_21155548):

> The part of the error message to helps identifying the problem is rejected HostKey: `github.com`.

If `ssh` doesn't find valid `id_rsa(.pub)` in `$HOME/.ssh`, then it looks for a `~/.ssh/config` file with a "`github.com`" entry in it which would tell ssh where to find the right ssh key to connect to the server represented by "`github.com`".

---

The issue was:

> Since I started gerrit with sudo, it was running as root. now I changes and it works fine

So if the keys were registered in a user `HOME`, they weren't visible by a process launched by root.

Comment: Ah, I was just about to write the same :-). This solution should help and the problem is that your ssh client (in the context of the Gerrit user) does not yet accept the key of github.com (you can solve this my getting it into the `known_hosts` file, or by disabling host key checking as shown by VonC.

Comment: The part of the error message to helps identifying the problem is `rejected HostKey: github.com`.

Comment: @StephenKing yes, I have edited the answer to better explain why.

Comment: What should be permission level for ~/.ssh/config ? 777 ?
I have added the file. Should i give my user_name for User in that file ? I tried that also. Still I am facing the same error.

Comment: @Virtual never 7 on the last bit. Check the all permission issue with http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309. For `config`, `chmod 600` should be enough

Comment: @VonC, Thanks. But still I don't see it working. I am getting the same "reject HostKey: github.com" . I don't understand, what I miss.

Comment: @Virtual did you check what user is executing your gerrit process? Is HOME correctly set for that user? Are all parent folders (/, /home/ /home/xxx) protected against write for group (chmod 755 only)?

Comment: @VonC, Thanks. replication started working. Since I started gerrit with sudo, it was running as root. now I changes and it works fine. Facing another problem now. Posted a new question for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159160/gerrit-remote-rejected-head-refs-for-master-internal-server-error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45363/discussion-between-virtual-and-vonc)