# GERRIT: ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (internal server error)

Tags: git, push, gerrit

It was working fine. Now, when I try to push

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

I get,

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 310 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 2, done    
To ssh://vinoth.pramati@192.168.6.9:29412/gerrit_prj_1
 **! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (internal server error)**
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://vinoth.pramati@192.168.6.9:29412/gerrit_prj_1'
```

In the gerrit_server error log, i see,

```
[2014-01-16 15:57:03,722] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : Only 0 of 1 new change refs created in gerrit_prj_1; aborting
```

I am using gerrit 2.8.13

Please help

Comment: Did you do rebase before push?

Comment: @cppcoder, no.
 
Even, I tried clonint it freshly oce again; made a change; committed; and pushed to HEAD:refs/for/master . 

same error

Comment: That seems related to https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1593

Comment: @VonC, I have got a clue on this. When I start the gerrit-server as root, i could push from my local machine. But, as root, the replication shows error. When I start the gerrit-server without root, I couldn't push. But, replication works only this way. So, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Virtual most probable cause: a difference in the environment: one session finds the ssh keys in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, the other don't.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by just logging into my repository from ssh
>> ssh git@github.com
It connected as the repository key were already in my computer.
Then , git pushed my code to master
>> git push origin master

Answer (score 2):

I use VSCode. I got this error today when I tried to push my repository to GitHub:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (Internal Server Error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git'
```

It happened several times. Then I just pulled the repository and then pushed it again and the problem resolved.

Comment: Repeatedly pulling and pushing eventually got one through. But the next commit did not work again. So I feel like this might simply be a GitHub problem currently?

Comment: This is due to an incident on GitHub's side that they are currently investigating https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/83lq7ftk19r5