# Gerrit replicating to gitolite fails

Tags: git, replication, gerrit, jsch, jgit

I have configured the replication with following configurations

```
$cat /var/gerrit/review_site/etc/replication.config
[gerrit]
  autoReload=true
[remote "bt-git"]
  projects = ^vt-(.*)$
  push = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
  url = git@git.something.com:/${name}.git
```

My ssh config file looks like this one,

```
Host git
  HostName git.something.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Although I have already added the right set of hostkeys in my ~/.ssh/known_hosts the replication plugin fails with the following stacktrace

```
[2017-08-02 13:08:55,194] [a6b3228d] Replication to git@git.something.com:/vt-test.git started...
[2017-08-02 13:08:55,320] [a6b3228d] Push to git@git.something.com:/vt-test.git references: [RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/heads/master, NOT_ATTEMPTED, (null)...990c876ff3860fbfd421a9785c87506126b89d1b, srcRef=refs/heads/master, message=null]]
[2017-08-02 13:08:55,379] [a6b3228d] Cannot replicate to git.something.com:/vt-test.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git.something.com:/vt-test.git: reject HostKey: git.something.com
    at      org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)    
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshPushConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openPush(TransportGitSsh.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1272)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1318)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:437)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:416)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:318)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:86)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:284)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:281)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:221)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:200)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: git.something.com
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:791)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)
    ... 24 more
```

However I am able to clone the repository from the same machine and it works seamlessly.

Comment: jsch is probably not reading the openssh configuration.

Comment: Is there something I can do to make jsch read the openssh configs?

Comment: Which version of JGit are you using?

Comment: I could not figure that out as I am not a Java person, but this the repository link for the replication plugin https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+/v2.13.5

Comment: Please try to set the `Host` line to `Host git.something.com`.

Comment: The SSH config is really for the user running Gerrit, not your personal one, right?